# How can I get all the dynamic selected check box along with the text box value on submit button click?

Tags: jquery

There is a list of check boxes dynamically generated.
Along with each check box there is an input box.

How can I get all the dynamic selected check box along with the text box value on submit button click ?

Creating check boxes

```
function addCheckbox(name) {
   var container = $('#cblist');
   var inputs = container.find('input');
   var id = inputs.length+1;

   $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'+id, value: name }).appendTo(container);
   $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb'+id, text: name }).appendTo(container);
}
```

Comment: show the dynamic way that you have used to create checkboxes

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi question updated

Comment: You are only  adding the checkbox? where is the correspond textbox for each checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

You can find checked checkboxes by using the `input[type=checkbox]:checked` property.

```js
let checkedCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');

checkedCheckboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
  console.log(`checked checkbox id: ${checkbox.id}`);
  console.log(`label: ${checkbox.labels[0].textContent}`);
});
```

```html
<label for="cb1">label 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" checked>

<label for="cb2">label 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2">

<label for="cb3">label 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb3" checked>
```